# How to use jps -Joption

Tags: java, jvm

I really can't figure out how to use jsp -Joption. I got description as followed,

> OPTIONS
>          The  jps command supports a number of options that modify the output of the command.  These options are subject to change or removal in the
>          future.

```
   -q             Suppress the output of the class name, JAR file name, and arguments passed to the main method,  producing  only  a  list  of
                  local VM identifiers.

   -m             Output the arguments passed to the main method. The output may be null for embedded JVMs.

   -l             Output the full package name for the application's main class or the full path name to the application's JAR file.

   -v             Output the arguments passed to the JVM.

   -V             Output  the  arguments  passed  to  the  JVM  through  the  flags  file  (the  .hotspotrc  file or the file specified by the
                  -XX:Flags=<filename> argument).

   -Joption       Pass option to the java launcher called by javac. For example, -J-Xms48m sets the startup memory to 48 megabytes.  It  is  a
                  common convention for -J to pass options to the underlying VM executing applications written in Java.
```

Actually, I don't know what is a `java launcher called by javac`, and when I run the example `jps -J-Xms48m`  just as same using `jps`. So, what this option for? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Java development tools like `jps`, `jstat`, `jstack`, `jmap` etc. are all written in Java. Just like regular Java programs they require Java Runtime Environment, i.e. they run under JVM.

`-J` options do not affect `jps` tool directly, but they rather affect the JVM which runs this tool. E.g. `-J-Xms48M` option means that `jps` will launch Java Virtual Machine with the initial heap size of 48 Megabytes.

For example, compare `jps -J-XX:+PrintGCDetails` and `jps -J-Xms48M -J-XX:+PrintGCDetails`

Comment: I got it! Thanks!